# Array length question

Tags: optimization, compiler-optimization

This question concerns optimization. Suppose I need the array length of an array A at two places in my code. Should I use the function a.length() in the two places, or is it faster to assign a local variable the value of a.length() and use it at the two places.

By "faster" I mean in terms of running time. Moreover, i am talking asymptotically.

Comment: What language and what data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asymptotic complexity of calling the function twice is the same - any constant number of calls to the same (pure) function on the same arguments has the same asymptotic complexity as a single call to that function, since you can just roll the constant number of calls into the big-O's hidden constant.

As for what will be faster, there's no guarantee which one will be faster.  It depends on the language and compiler.  I'd suggest just writing it both ways and timing the result to see if there's an appreciable difference.  That said, if you are writing something that is so performance-critical that you can't afford to call `.length()` twice, you may need to reconsider your approach in general to see if there's a better global solution to the problem.  Microoptimizations are rarely worth the effort unless you have a compelling reason to believe that your program is markedly slower in the unoptimized version.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to ask the question, you're not at a point where it matters yet.  If you were, you'd already have code that you've profiled, and you could just try it and see.  This kind of thing depends heavily on your language and compiler, and the only results that matter are the ones you see.

Don't worry about micro-optimizations til you find you need to shave cycles, and even then the algorithm is the first thing to check.

Answer (score 0):

What language? In many languages, such calls are optimized away (either at compile time or by a JIT compiler) into direct access to the length field of the array object.